# What values are expected in OpenAPI 3.0 "Security" array?

Tags: openapi

The OpenAPI 3.0 [docs about apiKey security](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/) have left me confused about the use of a field in the 'security' component of the specification. What is the purpose of the array value on the field that points to one of the defined securitySchemes.

Place holder keys?  Nothing?

```xml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:        
      type: apiKey
      in: header       
      name: X-API-KEY  

security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []     <-- What's the array for?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This array contains a list of required scopes, but the "API key" security scheme does not use scopes. Scopes are only used with OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect security schemes. There's an [enhancement request](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1366) to allow scopes for API keys too.